# javascript get img src from another websit

Tags: javascript

There is a website that has a picture updated every few hours. This image has an id.
for example:

```
<img id="theimage" src="https://www.google.co.il/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
```

This image changes every few hours but the id of the element remains the same.
I want to display the image on my website that is updated all the time. Is it possible to access this element from my site and extract the img src from it in javascript?
Thank you!

Comment: What is your backend running on? 

Comment: Yes, it is *possible*.

Comment: @deEr. I don't have a backend, it's a simple html page without anything else. thanks!

Comment: @possum How is this possible? 

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using JavaScript by making an HTTP request to the website and then parsing the HTML content to extract the `src` attribute of the image with the specified id. Here's a sample code snippet:

```js
// Make an HTTP GET request to the website
fetch('https://www.example.com')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    // Create a temporary element to hold the HTML content
    const tempElement = document.createElement('div');
    tempElement.innerHTML = html;

    // Find the image element by its id
    const imageElement = tempElement.querySelector('#theimage');

    // Check if the image element exists
    if (imageElement) {
      // Extract the src attribute value
      const imageUrl = imageElement.getAttribute('src');
      console.log('Image URL:', imageUrl);

      // Now you can use the imageUrl as the source for an <img> element on your website
    } else {
      console.log('Image element not found');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
```

This code fetches the HTML content of the website, creates a temporary element to hold it, finds the image element with the specified id, extracts the `src` attribute value, and then you can use this URL as the source for an `<img>` element on your website. Make sure to replace `'https://www.example.com'` with the actual URL of the website you want to fetch the image from. Be aware of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) restrictions when making requests to external websites from JavaScript.

Comment: This will work unless the image is generated dynamicaly with JS.